# Setup Yii 2 Web Framework Coding Standard in NetBeans

Tags: php, netbeans, yii, yii2, phpcodesniffer

I read [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-coding-standards) and [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/internals/core-code-style.md). But how to setup this in NetBeans IDE in Windows machine?

Answer (score 3):

**Yii2** requires **PHP 5.4** minimum, so if your IDE supports PHP 5.4 or later then it will show standards for Yii2 too.

You can also check this yii pligin for netbeans http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/47246/php-yii-framework-netbeans-phpcc

Comment: i mean how to add yii2 coding standards in the form of codesniffer to NetBeans

Comment: The plugin listed above is for Yii 1.  Here is the URL for Yii 2  https://github.com/nbphpcouncil/nb-yii2-plugin

Comment: Looks like you would need to install PHP_CodeSniffer, then configure it based on the instructions on the link you have above.  https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-coding-standards#php_codesniffer `$ ./vendor/bin/phpcs --extensions=php --standard=Yii2 /home/resurtm/work/Yii2MegaApp/`

Comment: This might be useful as well.  You can get some of the standards setup using editorconfig   https://github.com/boo1ean/generator-yii/blob/master/.editorconfig   https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/internals/core-code-style.md

Answer (score 0):

in root of your project make file with name of **autocompletion.php**   and add this to file.

```
 /**
 * Yii bootstrap file.
 * Used for enhanced IDE code autocompletion.
 * Note: To avoid "Multiple Implementations" PHPStorm warning and make autocomplete faster
 * exclude or "Mark as Plain Text" vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php file
 */
class Yii extends \yii\BaseYii
{
    /**
     * @var BaseApplication|WebApplication|ConsoleApplication the application instance
     */
    public static $app;
}

/**
 * Class BaseApplication
 * Used for properties that are identical for both WebApplication and ConsoleApplication
 *
 * @property trntv\filekit\Storage $fileStorage
 * @property common\components\keyStorage\KeyStorage $keyStorage
 * @property yii\web\UrlManager $urlManagerFrontend UrlManager for frontend application.
 * @property yii\web\UrlManager $urlManagerBackend UrlManager for backend application.
 * @property yii\web\UrlManager $urlManagerStorage UrlManager for storage application.
 * @property trntv\glide\components\Glide $glide
 * @property trntv\bus\CommandBus $commandBus
 */
abstract class BaseApplication extends yii\base\Application
{
}

/**
 * Class WebApplication
 * Include only Web application related components here
 *
 * @property User $user User component.
 */
class WebApplication extends yii\web\Application
{
}

/**
 * Class ConsoleApplication
 * Include only Console application related components here
 */
class ConsoleApplication extends yii\console\Application
{
}

/**
 * User component
 * Include only Web application related components here
 *
 * @property \common\models\User $identity User model.
 * @method \common\models\User getIdentity() returns User model.
 */
class User extends \yii\web\User
{
}
```